# catkin_make require build of package without dependencies

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a driver package for our hardware we have developed ourselves, which I shall call `foo_driver`. On our test desktop environment, we do not need the package, so there are no dependencies in the `package.xml` files of other packages, so it never builds on the desktop as expected.

However, we now want to run a QA tool on the library, which according to our QA department requires the standard `catkin_make` to try to build the library. We cannot ask for a single package build with `catkin_make --pkg foo_driver` apparently, so is there some way to flag a library as "Always build" or something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322557/catkin_make-require-build-of-package-without-dependencies/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2019-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your driver package has a manifest file `catkin_make` always builds all packages in a workspace. The dependencies only determine the order

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2019-05-06**:
Oops, just checked and there is a `if (${CMAKE_DEB_HOST_ARCH} MATCHES "amd642) return() endif()` at the top of the `CMakeLists.txt` making it not build on the desktop.